# How do I re-position the displayed image on my laptop?

Tags: resolution, display-settings, laptop-display

I want to re-position the display on my ASUS K53SM laptop's screen because I somehow managed to damage some portion of it (and I don't want to spend on this laptop for the time being).

Please refer the following image:

[image]

I changed the resolution from 1366x768 to 1280*768 to avoid the bad portion of the screen, but the screen is now centered and the right portion of my screen is now rendered useless.

What I want to do is, set a custom resolution of my laptop and re-position it in a way that is utilizes all the working area of my screen.

How do I re-position the displayed image on my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Laptops don't have the vertical/horizontal position settings that standard TFT screens have so  I don't think you'll have any luck doing what you're trying to do. Also, most laptops will auto-adjust to ensure the aspect ratio is kept (and centered) - hence the "wasted part of screen" effect you are witnessing.

Quite simply: your screen is broken - replace it, use an external VGA or keep viewing the resolution you have and love the "wasted part of screen".